# LSZ reduction formula for scalar field

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, operators, time-evolution, s-matrix-theory

I am using Schwartz QFT and the LSZ reduction formula at pp 70. The scalar field was written as
$$
\phi(x)=\phi(\vec{x}, t)=\int \frac{d^3 p}{(2 \pi)^3} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \omega_p}}\left[a_p(t) e^{-i p x}+a_p^{\dagger}(t) e^{i p x}\right]\tag{6.7}
$$
Where $e^{ipx}$ is four-vector exponentiation. But here is one problem, both the exponential and the creation and annihilation operators are time dependent. But as per I know the time dependence can reside at any one of the factors, either at $a_p$ or $a^\dagger_p$ or at $e^{ipx}$. From Heisenberg eqn of motion for simple harmonic Hamiltonian
$$
\frac{da_p}{dt}=i[H,a_p]
$$
from here we get
$$
a_p(t)=a_p(0)e^{-i\omega_p t}
$$
Incorporating this in
$$
\phi(x)=\phi(\vec{x}, t)=\int \frac{d^3 p}{(2 \pi)^3} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \omega_p}}\left[a_p(t) e^{-i \vec{p}.\vec{x}}+a_p^{\dagger}(t) e^{i \vec{p}.\vec{x}}\right]
$$
We get the mode expansion for the scalar field
$$
\phi(x)=\phi(\vec{x}, t)=\int \frac{d^3 p}{(2 \pi)^3} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \omega_p}}\left[a_p(0) e^{-i px}+a_p^{\dagger}(0) e^{i px}\right]
$$

Now in the first eqn Schwartz interestingly defined $$a_p(t)=e^{-i\omega_p t}a_p(0)e^{i\omega_p t}$$ as the time evolution of $a_p$.

So I was trying to think in this way, define $\mathcal{U}=e^{-i\omega_p t}$, then the same expression for the scalar field mode expansion,
$$
\phi(x)=\phi(\vec{x}, t)=\int \frac{d^3 p}{(2 \pi)^3} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \omega_p}}\left[\mathcal{U}a_p(0)\mathcal{U^\dagger}\mathcal{U} e^{-i \vec{p}.\vec{x}}+\mathcal{U^\dagger}a_p^\dagger(0)\mathcal{U}\mathcal{U^\dagger} e^{-i \vec{p}.\vec{x}}\right]
$$
Then we may get time dependence in both the factors. My question is this correct thinking?

Another problem is is it given when $t\rightarrow -\infty,\infty$, $\partial_t a_p(t)=0$ which means in asymptotic times, $a_p(t)$ are not dependent on time. How to prove it.

Comment: TBH I find Schwartz derivation with time-dependent creation and annihilation operators a bit confusing. A more transparent derivation IMO can be found e.g. in Maggiore and Itzykson & Zuber. The basic point is that the interacting field $\phi(x)$ asymptotes to in/out fields in the asymptotic region of spacetime $$\phi(x)\to \sqrt{Z}\phi^{\rm in/out}(x),\quad t\to \pm \infty,$$ where $Z$ is something called wavefunction renormalization (the reason for $\sqrt{Z}$ is very well explained in Itzykson & Zuber for example).

Comment: The in/out fields $\phi^{\rm in/out}(x)$ then have a free field expansion containing the creation and annihilation operators for in/out scattering states. In particular, the ${\cal S}$-matrix is $$\langle 0|a^{\rm out}(p_1)\cdots a^{\rm out}(p_n)a^{\rm in}(q_1)^\dagger\cdots a^{\rm in}(q_m)^\dagger |0\rangle$$ and then you can substitute $a^{\rm out}(p_i)$ and $a^{\rm in}(q_i)^\dagger$ in terms of $\phi^{\rm in/out}(x)$ using the Klein-Gordon inner product and then relate to $\phi(x)$ using the relation between them.

Comment: this part is fine, but my question is on the mode expansion of $\phi(x)$

Comment: how to simultaniously incorporate time dependence on both $a_p$ and exponential factor

Comment: The in/out fields have a mode expansion *by definition*. The interacting field $\phi(x)$ only has such a mode expansion in the asymptotic region because of its relation to in/out fields, which in turn is something we propose to incorporate the idea that asymptotically the field becomes free.

Comment: yes, but how $\partial_t a_p(t)=0$ in the asymptotic region